# A cyclic inequality for a real vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$. A set of $n$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ in $V \oplus V^*$ is called good if
$$
(x_1,y_1) +\dotsb+ (x_n,y_n) \geq (x_1,y_2) + (x_2,y_3) + \dotsb + (x_n,y_1).
$$
If $V$ is one-dimensional, then a set of points is good if all of its subsets of cardinality $2$ are good.

Is it true that if $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{R}}V=m<n$, then a set of $n$ points is good if all of its subsets of cardinality $m+1$ are good?

Comment: $(1, 1), (10, 3), (100, 2)$ is "good", but $(10, 3), (100, 2)$ is not. I think you may need to rethink your definition of "good". I would guess that it has to do with all permutations, not just the cycle.

Comment: @user44191 yes, there was a mistake. Removed an extra 'f'.

Comment: What is the definition of $\ge$ on $V \oplus V^*$?

Comment: @LSpice we mean the bilinear pairing and the $\geq$ on the reals

Comment: A set is usually unordered. Do you mean a sequence of $n$ points?